# Http keep-alive conncetion - response delimiter

Tags: http, http-headers

Hi i am writing a custom http server. At first i had only one request at one connection possible(Connection: close), everything was ok. But once i remade it connecton: keep-alive logic(more requests at one connection), my images stopped displaying. I think, it may be a problem with http response delimiters. Are there any? Or how can browser detect, that current http response is complete? thx

Comment: Why are you writing a custom http server?

Comment: Here's the RFC for persistent HTTP connections: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the response is guided by the `Content-Length` header or by using [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).